# Creating a list from network messages c++

Tags: c++, list

Quick question (I hope...)

I currently have some old code that I am trying to rewrite. The old code used a manual linked list. I am trying to convert this to a std::list in C++. Currently the list gets populated from a network message it receives that is 5 words big. So in my header file I declare the following:

```
std::list<int*> msg;
```

Then where I am handling my messages in my cpp file I have the following code:

```
msg.push_back(recvBuf);
```

I have a few questions here...

1. Am I doing this right first of all? Will the list allocate enough space to store all 5 words from my recvBuf?
2. Will pushing back the recvBuf cause it to be overwritten when I get new message in? I have read that push_back creates a copy of the memory but I want to double check here to make sure I understand what is going on.
3. I am new to lists in C++ in general. I am trying to use them here because from doing some reading I believe it is the best implementation. Can someone please explain to me if this is true and if not what would be the best implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: `std::list` does make a copy, but `std::list<int*> msg;` says it will make a copy of a pointer. The data *pointed at* can be easily and independently  overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend creating a structure for your messages:

```
struct Message
{
   int  payload[MAXIMUM_PAYLOAD_SIZE];
};
```

Then using a list of `Message`:

```
std::list<Message>  my_messages;
```

You could also create a `vector` of `Message` as well.

This relieves you from the hassles of dynamic memory allocation and object ownership and smart pointers that are associated with pointers.

This also fits your description of "a list of messages".

Another advantage is you can easily pass the `Message` to other functions and not worry about array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First you probably want to have queue instead of list , second you probably want to have `vector<uint8> buffer` to store a message and then push back on message queue , you can copy your recvmsg directly to buffer and it will allocate memory you need the size of message you will need to make proper constructor for that or function , not sure you network structure , but here is the sample:

```
class MessageHandler
{
public:
    MessageHandler(){}
    Message GetMessage(); // return message from front of queue
private:
    std::queue<Messages> msg;
};

class Messages
{
public:
    Messages(char* data,int size);
    Messages(const Messages& msg);
    std::vector<uint8> buffer;// buffer to store your message
    //if you have fixed size of buffer you can use array instead
};
```